# Parse string to object

Tags: javascript, c#

i have created a table in javascript :

```
var global = [];
            function GetValues() {
                debugger;
                var myList = $("#multiSelect");
                var yy = $("#article").val();

                var Selectedelement = $("#quantiCommande").val();
                myList.append('<option value=' + Selectedelement + '>' + Selectedelement + " " + yy + '</option>');
                global.push({ "id": yy, "qte": Selectedelement });

            }
```

i want now to send table global to the controller and this the code of method javasript that send table glabal to the controller:
and this is the form of  my table in javascript:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PSPoP.png)

```
 function Test() {

                var NumCommande = $("#NumCommande").val();
                var client = $("#clientc").val();
                debugger;
                $.ajax({
                    url: "/Commande/Ajoutercommande?NumCommande=" + NumCommande + "&client=" + client + "&global=" + global,   //          /Controlleur/Action 
                    type: "POST",
                    dataType: 'text',
                    //data : {Nom: nom},
                    success: function (responseText) {
                        debugger;
                        if (responseText == "True") {
                            alert("Succes");
                        }
                        else {
                            alert("error");
                        }
                    }
                });

            }
```

and this is my controller methode i need to display the element of my table global

```
 public Boolean Ajoutercommande(string NumCommande, int client, Object global)
    {

        CRUDEntities db = new CRUDEntities();
        Commande c = new Commande();
        c.NumCommande = NumCommande;
        c.Quantité = client;
        Console.Write(global);
        db.Commande.Add(c);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return true;

        return true;
    }
```

can someone help me to fix this code and thank you.

Comment: i need the content of global to insert any  id and qte in table commande

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend to create one single object parameter.
Define your datacontract

```
public class TableContent 
{
     public int id { get; set; }
     public string qte { get; set; }
}

public class AjourtercommandParam 
{
     public string NumCommande { get; set; }
     public int client { get; set; }
     public TableContent[] global { get; set; }
}
```

then, in your controller (WebApi controller, right?)

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("Commande/Ajoutercommande")]    
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Ajoutercommand(AjoutercommandParam param)
{
     if(ModelState.IsValid == false)
     {
          return BadRequest(ModelState);
     }
     try
     {
         var result = await DataLayerService.AjouterCommand(param);
         return Ok(result);
     }
     catch (Exception ex)
     {
         return BadRequest(ex.Message);
     }
}
```

Post your data in the data section of the ajax call.

```
$.ajax({
                    url: "/Commande/Ajoutercommande",
                    type: "POST",
                    dataType: 'json',
                    data : {
                       "NumCommande": NummCommande,
                       "client" : client,
                       "global" : global
                    },
                    success: function (responseText) {
                        debugger;
                        if (responseText == "True") {
                            alert("Succes");
                        }
                        else {
                            alert("error");
                        }
                    }
                });
```

Comment: This is good, but to be complete you need to show him how to include this as the data object in the ajax call, rather than in the URL string as he is currently doing.

Comment: I just updated. For more detailed info about posting in the body part of the POST statement, r code have to look it up, I'm using angularjs methods, mostly :)